# What to do when someone 'manually migrates' a question to another site and drops an answer?

Tags: discussion, migration

Recently, a question asked here which I answered has been deleted by the owner and reasked on a (then) private beta site, [quantum computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com).

I don't think that such a 'manual migration' is a good idea, in particular because my answer to the question got deleted in the process.

For this case, I decided to simply re-post my answer on the moved question, similar to an actual migration.

I didn't really mind, as I'm active on that site as well. So, I'm not asking what to do with that example.

However, I'm not aware of any policy or accepted methods to deal with this situation. So, what should I do if I encounter a similar situation in the future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only policy I'm aware of is described at [Self-deleted questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1252/755).

To summarize: Deleting a question that has already been answered is generally discouraged, as part of our mission is to help not only the person who posted the question but also others who might have a similar question in the future, and deleting the question arguably wastes the time of the person who answered.  If you see that happen, and if you think it was a good question and a good answer that's likely to be useful to others in the future, flag it for moderator attention and we can undelete if that seems like the best solution.

In the specific case you mention (where it is subsequently posted on a private beta), I don't know what the best resolution in that particular situation is.  Your solution seems like a reasonable one and maybe about as good an outcome as is possible given the circumstances.

Related: [Self-deleted questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1252/755), [Better oversight for self-deleted answered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244839/160917), [Another self-deleted question](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1414/755).

Comment: Do note that the resolution I made is only possible when the 'lost answer' is authored by me. I think that if that isn't the case, requesting undeletion might be better. After that, I can simply leave a comment below the answer that the answer could also 'move along' if the answerer wants to do so.

Comment: @Discretelizard, yup.  That makes sense to me.  (One reason this particular situation is a little complicated is that we probably don't want to have two copies of the question open on two different Stack Exchange sites; and not all of us have visibility into a private beta.)  Anyway, seems like you handled it as well as possible, given the situation.

Comment: Note that after undeletion, we can migrate and the questions can then be merged on the target site. Works for all non-private-beta-sites.